# Accessing API with Client credential flow for first time

Tags: azure, api, rest, security, authentication

I get the client credential flow but how does the client get initially identified or authenticated for the first time of accessing the protected resource?

If it was a Client Secret I'd distribute that manually, do you need to issue the client with a public certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to access Azure AD secured resource, no need to issue the client with a public certificate, you just need to use the client id and client secret to [get the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), then [use the token to call the API you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#use-a-token).

Comment: Thanks Joy, it is understood now, basically you are adding a second layer of auth through the signed approved token.